# Why does npm leave a mess in my home folder?

Tags: node.js, npm

I noticed that when I install packages, even globally, they and their dependencies get put in `~/.npm` and are never removed even after uninstalling packages where the dependencies are no longer needed. Why is this? What's the purpose of the `~/.npm` folder and how do I clean it up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[It's a cache.](https://npmjs.org/doc/cache.html)  It makes installing things quicker.

If you want to empty it run:

```
npm cache clean
```